# Android webView doesn't come back after login on Facebook?

Tags: java, android, android-webview, facebook-login

Im not and Android or Java Developer, I fullstack web developer..but I have a template for making webviews project that works in most of the cases...but with this login doesnt work..

I have a site tha use the facebook Js SDK Version 3.2

**It works perfect on**: Google Chrome in my Laptop.

**It works perfect on**: Google Chrome in my Phone

but in APP in the webView after i Insert user and password of Facebook and press login it freezes.
I think it cant return to the previous page..

I read a lot of post here but nothing works..

this is my MainActivity:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.net.http.SslError;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.SslErrorHandler;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebResourceError;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebResourceResponse;

import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String target_url = "https://myapp.com/gen_age/index.php";
    private static final String target_url_prefix = "myapp.com/gen_age/index.php";
    private WebView mWebview;
    private WebView mWebviewPop;
    private FrameLayout mContainer;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);

        mWebview = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mContainer = findViewById(R.id.webview_frame);
        swipeLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);

        final WebSettings webSettings = mWebview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new UriWebViewClient());
        mWebview.setWebChromeClient(new UriChromeClient());
        mWebview.loadUrl(target_url);


        swipeLayout.setRefreshing(true);

        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {

            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                //Do your task
                mWebview.reload();
            }
        });

    }

    private class UriWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
            swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedHttpError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceResponse errorResponse) {
            super.onReceivedHttpError(view, request, errorResponse);
            swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(final WebView view, final String url) {

            try {

                String host = Uri.parse(url).getHost();
                //Log.d("shouldOverrideUrlLoading", url);
                if (host.equals(target_url_prefix)) {
                    // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load
                    // the page
                    if (mWebviewPop != null) {
                        mWebviewPop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mContainer.removeView(mWebviewPop);
                        mWebviewPop = null;
                    }
                    return false;
                }

                if (host.equals("m.facebook.com")) {
                    return false;
                }




            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

//            swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            Log.d("onReceivedSslError", "onReceivedSslError");
            //super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mWebview.canGoBack()) {
            mWebview.goBack();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }

    class UriChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog,
                                      boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
            mWebviewPop = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
            mWebviewPop.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            mWebviewPop.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
            mWebviewPop.setWebViewClient(new UriWebViewClient());
            mWebviewPop.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebviewPop.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
            mWebviewPop.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            mContainer.addView(mWebviewPop);
            WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
            transport.setWebView(mWebviewPop);
            resultMsg.sendToTarget();

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCloseWindow(WebView window) {
            Log.d("onCloseWindow", "called");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna go out on a limb here and say you are doing IO operations (like trying to login by sending credentials over the internet) on the **main UI thread**. If this is the case, this is what is causing your app to freeze.

I couldn't find the actual code that is responsible for the login, but, if you are sending an HTTP request or something similar to it, **you need to do it in a background thread**, so that UI doesn't freeze.

The main thread in Android is responsible for updating the UI, and if you block it with a **blocking IO operation**, it will freeze.

Comment: Daniel can you explain a little more...as I say Im not an android developer. This is webview of a site I made. and works ok on browsers.

Comment: @JonTargaryen browsers are not the same as apps. You are not allowed to do time consuming tasks (like login) on the main thread. In JavaScript for example, if you want to execute code that does a login task, you do in an asynchronous manner. However, in android (and iOS as well), you need to start *another* thread, that will do the login task, otherwise the main thread will not be freed up until the login task is complete.

Comment: @JonTargaryen have a read here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting#intro